# How to change a html page from flask to Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on an app that requires changing a flask template to that of Django.How to change the url_for('function') in the html page

Answer (score 1):

In Django you can use:

```
{% url 'some-url-name' %}
```

You can also add params as follows:

```
{% url 'some-url-name' param1=val1 param2=val2 %}
```

With `some-url-name` is the name that you give to the `url` associated with your `view` like the  following:

```
url(r'^some-url/', 'myapp.views.some_view', name='some-url-name')
```

If you want to use url namespaces, an example looks like this (we suppose `some-url-name` is the url name in `myapp/urls.py`):

```
url(r'^some-url/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp'))
```

In your template:

```
{% url 'myapp:some-url-name' param1=val1 param2=val2 %}
```

**Some differences with static files:**

*In Flask:*

```
url_for('static', filename='path/to/file')
```

*In Django:*

```
{% static "path/to/file" %}
```