# django url_for equivalent

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to find a django method that is equivalent to Flask's url_for.

I'm not looking for the jinja equivalent (as shown [here](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40313374/how-to-change-a-html-page-from-flask-to-django)) -- I'm talking about on the python side of the house

in my flask app I send an HTML string as follows:

```
my_picture = '<img src="{}">'.format(url_for('static', filename=r'images/myPic.jpg'))
```

I know I could do this in the html as `<img src={{ my_picture }}>` but that's not my goal.

What I've been doing is

```
from my_project.settings import STATIC_URL
my_picture = '<img src="{}">'.format(os.path.join('static', 'images/myPic.jpg'))
```

but there has to be a better way

Thanks!

Comment: I was using jinja in flask -- I'm explicitly not asking about the template language or any enriched HTML element. I'm looking for the python method @Daniel_Roseman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends what you're looking for.

## Static Files

If you want to get the URL for a [static file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/), you can use the following bit:

```
from django.templatetags.static import static

url = static('images/myPic.jpg')
```

## URL config

If you want to get the URL path of a named URL in your URL config, you can use the the `reverse` [URL resolver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse). Let's say your URL config looks like this:

If your URL config would look like this:

```
from example import views

path('my/fancy/example/', views.example, name='my-example-view')
```

Then you can get the URL with this:

```
from django.urls import reverse

url = reverse('my-example-view') # will return "my/fancy/example/"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the template tag in my python files as well when I need that:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static

url = static('images/myPic.jpg')
```

Comment: For completeness, the equivalent of the `{% url %}` templatetag in python code is `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse`.

Comment: how could this be generalized like the url_for method? So that it could be used w/ static, index, ... and all other pages?

Comment: It can’t. Static files and media files have nothing to do with your app urls because in a normal production environment they aren’t served by Django.

Comment: Please note `django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles.static` is deprecated in favor of `django.templatetags.static.static`